# Sorting SQL table results

Tags: sql, sorting

```
Name      Rank    XP
-----------------------
Craig     0       100
Morris    1       0
Roger     0       4000
```

I want my SQL statement to pull names from the above table in the order that the RANK field takes priority, followed by the XP field.

So the correct order would be;

```
Morris
Roger
Craig
```

I've tried a 'ORDER BY Rank ASC, XP DESC' but can't seem to get it to work.

Any tips?

Comment: what do you mean, "but can't seem to get it to work" ?  Show the query and the error message you are getting, please.

Comment: sounds like you need `Rank desc`?

Comment: Maybe you need ORDER BY Rank DESC, XP DESC? I agree that we need to see entire query and output.

Comment: My bad, how stupid of me :/ thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
ORDER BY [Rank] DESC, XP DESC
```

will produce

```
Morris
Roger
Craig
```

```
ORDER BY [Rank] ASC, XP DESC
```

will produce

```
Roger
Craig
Morris
```

Comment: I think the key distinction is that he should be ordering by rank descending instead of ascending.

Answer (score 0):

"RANK" is an SQL reserved word.  Try this:

```
ORDER BY [RANK] DESC, XP DESC
```